# H1B Status, married with 2 kids( US born), can i include them as Dependents if they stays with me less then 180 days?

Tags: dependents

I am on H1B visa status and saying in USA from last 5+ year. My wife staying with in usa from last 3+ years and i have two kids US born. Current year my wife and kids went to out of country more than 180 days. Can I include them in my Tax return as dependents( My wife has ITIN and kids has SSN)

Comment: Did you pay their expenses while they were outside the USA?